# fixupKeys() function in breeze.debug.js

Tags: breeze

```
  function fixupKeys(em, keyMappings) {
    keyMappings.forEach(function (km) {
        var group = em._entityGroupMap[km.entityTypeName];
        group._fixupKey(km.tempValue, km.realValue);            
    });
  }
```

For one of my entities, I am seeing group return undefined, and so throws an error with group._fixupKey().

It looks to me that the km.entityTypeName stores the short name of the entity, but the em._entityGroupMap stores a concatenated name of the entity with it's the namespace.

Anyone know if this a breezejs bug? Or am I doing something wrong in my model that is responsible for this mismatched key?

Comment: Tim, since we cannot reproduce it in our test suite, could you provide a small solution reproducing the problem? There's a chance that it might be related to some peculiarity in your model. Please send the repro to breeze@ideablade.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with the implementation of my custom breeze dataservice adapter. Thanks for looking at it with me.